# loop through array of dictionaries to find a value

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionaries that I would like to go through to find a matching value that I can then Count == Nth item of the array

Each item of the array looks like this

```
HMOD = 0;
MID = 39;
MOD = SOMETHING; // looking for this value
ID = 50;
```

So I would like to create a loop that goes through the array until it finds the matching value, then I use the number in the count as an reference to  Index path in the next view..

I have written this peice of code which dosnt work... but hopefully it gives you an idea of the loop I am trying to create.

```
int count = 0;
while (singleName != [[ModArray valueForKey:@"MOD"] objectAtIndex:count]) {
                    count ++;
                    NSLog(@"%i", count);
                }
```

SingleName is a NSString that I am using to match the MOD value in ModArray...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution by using `valueForKey` on the array of dictionaries,

Assuming that your `modArray` is like this,

```
NSArray *modArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"0" forKey:@"HMOD"],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"39" forKey:@"MID"],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"something" forKey:@"MOD"],
                       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"50" forKey:@"ID"], nil];
```

And `singleName` has a value as `"something"`

```
    NSString *singleName = @"something";
```

Fetch the `array` from `modArray` which has an object with key as `"MOD"`,

```
    NSArray *array = [modArray valueForKey:@"MOD"];
```

Check if `singleName` is present in this `array`. If yes, then get the first index of that object which will be same as the index of dictionary with key "`MOD`" in `modArray`.

```
    if ([array containsObject:singleName]) {
        NSLog(@"%d", [array indexOfObject:singleName]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ is not present in the array", singleName);
    }
```

**Update:**
If you want to do it in your way, only mistake was you were using `!=` whereas you should have used `isEqualToString`. You should have done like this,

```
int count = 0;
while (![singleName isEqualToString:[[modArray valueForKey:@"MOD"] objectAtIndex:count]]) {
                    count ++;
                    NSLog(@"%i", count);
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks all inside out. You state you have an array of dictionaries. Assuming `ModArray` is the array (based on the name) you might do this:

```
NSUInteger count = 0;
for (NSDictionary *dict in ModArray) { // iterate through the array
    NSString *mod = dict[@"MOD"];      // get the value for MOD
    if ([mod isEqualToString:singleName]) {  // compare the two strings
        break;                         // they match so exit the loop
    }
    count++
}

// count has the index of the dictionary with the matching MOD value
```

Edit: Based on ACB correcting my misunderstanding of `NSArray valueForKey:`, the only real issue is your use of using != to compare the two strings.

Comment: You are wrong about #2 and #3. As per apple documentation on NSArray, valueForKey:
Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html However you are correct about #1 and your solution also works.

Comment: @ACB - thanks. After 4+ years of this stuff, I never knew about that `NSArray valueForKey:` method. I wish I had. :)  I'll update my answer.

Comment: :) Someone once said, it's never too late to learn something new.. :)

Comment: @ACB I have no issue admitting I don't know everything :) The API is MASSIVE. Finding little gems like this is part of the fun.

Comment: I completely agree with those second and third facts you mentioned. I am still learning new things every day while going through all these SO questions and answers. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
- This is Helpful when you search from Dictionary.

NSMutableArray *contentList;
NSMutableArray *filteredContentList;
BOOL isSearching;

// firstSection is array which already filled.
// contentList array for value of particular key
// filteredContentList is search array from actual array.

  - (void)searchTableList {
        NSString *searchString = searchBar.text;

        NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"frame_code beginswith[c] %@", searchString];
        NSArray *filteredArr = [firstSection filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
        if(contentList.count > 0)
            [contentList removeAllObjects];
        [filteredContentList addObjectsFromArray:filteredArr];
    }

    - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1 {

        if ([searchBar1.text length] != 0)
            isSearching = YES;
        else
            isSearching = NO;
    }

    - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
        NSLog(@"Text change - %d",isSearching);

        //Remove all objects first.
        [filteredContentList removeAllObjects];

        if([searchText length] != 0) {
            isSearching = YES;
            [self searchTableList];
        }
        else {
            isSearching = NO;
        }
        [tblFrameList_SComplete reloadData];
    }

    - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
        NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
    }

    - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
        NSLog(@"Search Clicked");
        [self searchTableList];
    }
```